# Settings.js:168 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'component' of 'templates.find(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi guys  I am struggling to solve this error, here is my code

```
 import TemplateOne from "./Template_1";
      ..........
     
      const templates = [
       {
        title: "TemplateOne",
        component: TemplateOne,
        }
      ]
    
      const { component: SelectedComponent, title } = 
       templates.find(function (Component,idx){
       if (Component.id === templatesID.stid) {
          return true;
       }
        return false;
      });
```

And I am displaying the selected component like this :
`<SelectedComponent />`

[image]

**Note I have multiple templates**

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The `find` returns `undefined` if no element is found that match the provided testing function.

So you could save the result of `find` in a variable, check if is truthy and then destructure it.

Comment: @TheDeadMan are you sure that the `find` returns a template? Maybe it just don't find nothing so the return value is still `undefined`.
Can you `console.log` the return value of the `find`?

Comment: @TheDeadMan I updated the answer based on your question's edit.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value for find can be undefined, so you can't desctructre the result directly, just try this:

```
const currentTemplate = templates.find(function (Component,idx){
   if (Component.id === templatesID.stid) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
 });
```

and when you display the component

```
currentTemplate ? <currentTemplate.component /> : null
```